# USB C port seems dead - Thinkpad T580 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, c

On my new laptop one of the two USB 3 ports stopped functioning and as I didn't want to send it back for repairs I bought a USB C to USB 3 cable so as to have a spare, free, port. The second USB 3 port is running a hub and I have no problems with it.
The USB C port seems dead, on connecting the cable to a flash drive it is not recognised nor does it even charge a telephone. It looks completely dead.
In view of lots of other comments on AskUbuntu is this a Ubuntu problem ? 
I am not very knowledgable on Ubuntu so if anyone has any suggestions please keep it simple!
Thanks in advance for any help.
Bob

Comment: Connect a device to the USB port while watching the output of `sudo udevadm monitor` in a terminal window.  If activity shows up when you plug a USB drive or such in there, then it's possible it's Ubuntu.  If nothing shows up, then it's a hardware problem unrelated to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

0
down vote

I've had the same problem for two weeks and today I found a solution by simply buying another cable! This afternoon I received my 3rd "USB-C Male to USB-3 Female" adaptor and a flash drive showed up on the desktop! I don't know if I am allowed to write the make of this adaptor so I won't but the two previous ones from other manufacturers left me thinking that either the USB-C port on my new laptop was dead or that U!buntu 18.04 was incompatible with USB-C !!